# Google Scripts: Getting an array [ [x], [y] ] of nth length to return array of x/y values [ [x1,y1], [x2,y2], etc]

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, map-function

I have an array:

```
var array1 = [ ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"], ["ItemA","ItemB","ItemC","ItemD"] ];
```

Trying to get it set up in pairs to read:

```
[ ["Item1", "ItemA"], ["Item2", "ItemB"], ["Item3", "ItemC"], ["Item4", "ItemD"] }
```

I've been able to successfully do this by outputting the original array on a sheet, using the following 'transpose' function (found on this site) and then doing another getDataRange().getValues() call on the newly transposed sheet.

```
function transpose(destSheet) {

  var values = destSheet.getDataRange().getValues; 
  var values = range.getValues();

  // transpose it & write it out
  destSheet.getRange(1,1,values[0].length,values.length)
    .setValues(Object.keys(values[0]).map ( function (columnNumber) {
      return values.map( function (row) {
        return row[columnNumber];
      });
    }));
  
}
```

New to GAS so I've been frying my brain online trying to find an example of the map function to do on the array itself without having to paste it first to a sheet.

Comment: What is `destSheet`? this looks like a custom function. How do you use this function? BTW there is already a transpose built in function in google sheets. You can't use this as a custom function.

Comment: Thank you!!! Sorry I'm new to this and just checked out the transpose function and figured it out!!!  Thanks man - had zero idea and was going about it in the wrong way!!

Comment: Accepted! ;) Didn't even know about  'accepting' an answer seeing it's the 1st question I've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve from Google Apps Script prespective.

However, here is the javascript part that you need to accomplish your goal:

```js
const array1 = [
["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"], 
["ItemA","ItemB","ItemC","ItemD"]
];
const farray1 = array1[0].map((_, col) => array1.map(r => r[col]));
console.log(farray1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marios I got this to work no prob:

```
var array1 = [ ["Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4"], ["ItemA","ItemB","ItemC","ItemD"] ];
  Logger.log(array1);
  var array2 = Object.keys(array1[0]).map(function (c) { return array1.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
  Logger.log(array2);
```

Comment: this is kinda duplicate of my answer and I am not sure whether it adds extra value but glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Sorry, I retyped it out in GAS instead of Javascript.  This was my 1st question so wasn't aware of the accepting an answer, etc.  Thanks for the clue there.